Generalised wave equation from Maxwell's equations
I was playing around with Maxwell's equations and I've found a linear combination of the electric and magnetic fields which also satisfies a wave equation, but I don't know the implications of this.
I begin writing down Maxwell's equations in the vacuum (no charge, no current):
$$\vec \nabla \cdot \vec E =0
\\
\vec \nabla \cdot \vec B = 0
\\
\vec \nabla \times \vec E =-\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}
\\
\vec \nabla \times \vec B = \mu_0 \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}$$
Now, let us rewrite these equations in terms of the new field $\vec C = ic\vec B$ (its units, of course, coincide with those of the electric field).
$$\vec \nabla \cdot \vec E =0
\\
\vec \nabla \cdot \vec C =0
\\
\vec \nabla \times \vec E = \frac{i}{c}\frac{\partial \vec C}{\partial t}
\\
\vec \nabla \times \vec C =\frac{i}{c}\frac{\partial \vec E }{\partial t}$$
Now, by naming $\vec T=\vec E+\vec C$ and adding up the first and second, and the third and fourth equations, I get:
$$\vec \nabla \cdot \vec T =0
\\
\vec \nabla\times \vec T=\frac{i}{c}\frac{\partial \vec T}{\partial t}$$
And finally, using the identity: $\vec\nabla\times(\vec \nabla \times \vec F)=\vec \nabla(\vec \nabla\cdot \vec F)-\nabla^2\vec F$:
$$\boxed{\nabla^2\vec T-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \vec T}{\partial t}=0}$$
Therefore, the linear combination of the fields $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ also satisfies a wave equation, and I'm wondering if this would be of any interest. I don't think so though, since if we are in the vacuum, then both of these fields will obey their respective Helmholtz equations and therefore any linear combination of the fields will obey a wave equation. The linear combination I found would therefore just be a particular case.

What you have "discovered" is standard d'Alembert wave operator, $~\Box$.

This is a trivial result. In vacuum both $\mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r}, t)$ and $\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{r},t)$ satisfy wave equation, that is linear. No surprise at all that a linear combination of $\mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r},t)$ and $\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{r},t)$ fields satisfies the same linear equation.
This result holds for every homogeneous linear problem, that can be formally written as $L v = 0$, with $L$ a linear operator so that $L(a+b) = La + Lb$, $L(\alpha a) = \alpha L a$, with $\alpha$ scalar. It immediately follows that $v$, $w$ satisfies the homogeneous linear equation, even a linear combination of these solution does,
$$L(\alpha v + \beta w) = \alpha \underbrace{L v}_{=0} + \beta \underbrace{Lw}_{ = 0 } = 0 \ .$$
For non-homogeneous linear problems, like Mawxell's equations with free charges and currents, the principle of superposition of causes and effects (PSCE) holds, namely
$$\begin{aligned} L v_1 & = j_1 \\ L v_2 & = j_2 \end{aligned} \quad \rightarrow \quad L(\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2) = \alpha_1 j_1 + \alpha_2 j_2 \ .$$
